# How can I find all my shared folders on Google Drive

Tags: google-drive

Is it possible to list all folders that you have shared?

Comment: A search for `to:` suffices to find anything that you've shared, so I was hoping that a search for `type:folder to:` would do it, but that doesn't seem to work. All I've got so far is that in your list of folders, the ones with a person icon in them are shared.

Comment: Thanks @AIE. Yes, to: gives you everything but this isn't very useful if you have shared a lot of stuff. The icon on the folder is more helpful but still not ideal.

Comment: I Guess what you are looking for is this Add-on :
https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/drive_manager/1049726953004

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution:

- connect your drive to [whohasaccess.com](https://www.whohasaccess.com/) which will build a list of people with access to your Google Drive, it will show:

  - Show all files and folders
  - Show only files and folders you can manage
  - Show only files and folders you own